# Yield used with Dynamic Object

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```vb
Private Iterator Function QueryCore(ByVal sql As String, Optional ByVal parms() As Object = Nothing) As IEnumerable(Of Object)
    Using connection = CreateConnection()
        Using command = CreateCommand(sql, connection, parms)
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                Do While reader.Read()
                    Yield reader.ToExpando()
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Function ToExpando(ByVal reader As IDataReader) As Object
    Dim dictionary = TryCast(New ExpandoObject(), IDictionary(Of String, Object))
    For i As Integer = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
        dictionary.Add(reader.GetName(i), If(reader(i) Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, reader(i)))
    Next i

    Return TryCast(dictionary, ExpandoObject)
End Function
```

Where is the `ExpandoObject` stored when it is returned by the `ToExpando` method?

I understand iterators that follow this syntax:

```cs
// Implementing the enumerable pattern
public System.Collections.IEnumerable SampleIterator(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}

ListClass test = new ListClass();

foreach (int n in test.SampleIterator(1, 10))
{
    System.Console.Write(n + " ");
}
```

When the `Yield` statement runs in `QueryCore`, control is not passed back to the caller. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: Maybe there are no results? ToExpando returns "an object" and it is "that object" which will be returned via yield. If the resulting IEnumerable is empty well.. then "no objects" were added to it. Also, perhaps step through with a debugger to isolate what "controlled is not passed back" means here.

Comment: _"When the Yield statement runs in QueryCore, control is not passed back to the caller"_ -- say who? The `Yield` statement always returns control to the caller of the `MoveNext()` method (implicit in `foreach` loops) used while enumerating the results of the declared method (`QueryCore()`, in this case). Why do you say otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The `ExpandoObject` is created on the heap by the `new ExpandoObject()` expression in the `dim` statement. Then it is returned by `ToExpando` then by `QueryCore` because of the `Yield`. Control is passed back by the `Yield` statement.